# How to count sum of prime numbers without a number 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, primes

I have to count the sum of all prime numbers that are less than 1000 and do not contain the digit 3.

My code:

```
def primes_sum(lower, upper):
    total = 0
    for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
        if not num % 3 and num % 10:
            continue
        elif num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if num % i == 0:
                    break
            else:
                total += num
    return total

total_value = primes_sum(0, 1000)
print(total_value)
```

But still I don't have right result

Comment: `if not num % 3 and num % 10:` is going to execute when `num` can be divided by 3 AND cannot be divided by 10. Remember that `0` is converted to `False` and any other number to `True`. It will exclude 3 numbers (10, 100 and 1000) in that step, which would be skipped anyway later. And numbers that can be divided by 3 are of course not primes, except for 3 itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def primes_sum(lower, upper):
    """Assume upper>=lower>2"""
    primes = [2]
    answer = 2
    for num in range(lower, upper+1):
        if any(num%p==0 for p in primes): continue  # not a prime

        primes.append(num)

        if '3' in str(num): continue
        answer += num

    return answer
```

The issue in your code was that you were checking for `num%3`, which checks whether `num` is divisible by 3, not whether it contains a `3`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but still I unfortunately cannot see a result

Comment: `print(primes_sum(3,1000))`

Comment: @regular_everyday_pythonist This code breaks if you provide a `lower` bound that is less than 2.

Comment: @picobit do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @regular_everyday_pythonist I was just pointing that out in case that was the problem that caused you to start this comment thread. There are no prime numbers lower than 2, so don't feed them into the function. Or you can `continue` if `num < 2`